# Custom dynamic routing and get ids from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model name "profit" and it has a table name profits and 3 column of the table "product_id", "client_id", "grossprofit"

Now in my index.html.erb page I have option for show as

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', profit %></td>
```

when I click on the show link i go to show page and link become

```
http://localhost:3000/profits/1
http://localhost:3000/profits/2
```

that is i am getting id of profits table but I need product_id and client_id in my url like below

```
http://localhost:3000/profits/3/5
```

where 3 will be product_id and 5 will be client_id

What changes I have to do to get this url and how can I get product_id and client_id from the url in show action of the controller?

Association among the models are

```
product: has_many  profits
client: has_many profits
profit: belongs to product and client
```

Comment: Need your routes.erb file, because nothing you've said shows why students should be involved.

Comment: sorry it will be profits. I updated the post

Comment: Ah that would explain it, some thing like what @HarsHarl suggested below is where you want to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes.rb

```
resources :profits do    
  get ":product_id/:client_id", :action => :show, :as => :show, :on => :collection
end
```

The view

```
<%= link_to 'Show', show_profits_path(profit.product_id, profit.client_id) %>
```

The development log when clicking the link is

```
Started GET "/profits/5/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-04 20:42:10 +0800
Processing by ProfitsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"product_id"=>"5", "client_id"=>"3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

you make wrong routes in routes.rb file please declare it as :

```
resources :profits do
 resources :products, :clients
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

As HarsHarl & cenyongh suggested, you'd be better looking at [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

The problem you've got is that you can't access the `product_id` and `client_id` vars, unless they're stored in a session. Because of this, you'll have to pass them through the URL

I'd use this:

```
resources :profits do
    get ":product_id/:client_id", to: "show"
end
```

This will create this route:

```
/profits/13/5
```

More importantly, it will pass these params: `product_id` and `client_id` to the show action