# Non resourceful routing and dynamic segmentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my route file

```
get '/registrations/:student_id/:subject_id' => "registrations#show", :as => 'custom'
```

Now I want to use this in link_to helper so that I can send student_id and subject_id to show action of the controller

```
<%= link_to "Custom" .... %>
```

Comment: looks like the problem is similar to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920551/custom-dynamic-routing-and-get-ids-from-url/20921157?noredirect=1#comment31411018_20921157

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have instance variables `@student_id` and `@subject_id` availeble to your view, then this should work:

```
<%= link_to "Custom", custom_path(@student_id, @subject_id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like similar to this question, the same solution can be applied. [Custom dynamic routing and get ids from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920551/custom-dynamic-routing-and-get-ids-from-url/20921157?noredirect=1#comment31411018_20921157)